# Using the word "murder" in "killer explosion"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I saw a post today on social media

"78 people were killed by the explosion in Lebanon"

And I commented "since you used the word "killer" rather than "died", can we assume it's a murder?"

I got hate comments suddenly and got confused, I know it's common to use killer in storms, earthquakes and such but can we also use the word murder?
Does using the word killer really is correct?

I'm confused, thanks for the answers

Comment: Kill is a neutral word for "to make someone die". People may be killed in an accident.

Murder is to kill someone deliberately with a malicious intent.

I think that that is why you received hate comments soon after.

Comment: Once upon a time, "to kill" mean what is now meant by murder.  (And "to murder" meant to assassinate.)  However, that was in Tudor times.  Now it just means "to cause a death" (which, at that time, was "to slay").

Comment: The problem may have been that you changed the ending of the word, changing the whole tenor of the report.

Comment: But is the "murder" word valid if the explosion was intentional? as if the "murder" is the person who made explosion and not the explosion itself?

Comment: @Shizukara: it is becoming clear that the explosion was not intentional, and people thought you were claiming it was. If it had been intentional, then you could use "murder".

Comment: You quote ***killed*** as what was originally posted. Yet your comment of "since you used the word '***killer***'" is wrong. The person making the post did *not* use the word *killer*.

Comment: Shizukura, don't you think you might find more suitable help at SE English Language Learners?